How can we point to a specific element of an abstract mathematical space that has no distinctive elements with respect to the space's structure?
An example of such a space is a Euclidean affine space. Consider the statement "point O is the origin of the system". How could we clearly specify and convey what point O is supposed to be, given that this space is "homogeneous" or "isotropic", i.e., everything "looks" the same? The structure a point "sees" in the space it "lives" in is the same for every point, so there is no distinguishing point. This is different from, for example, the natural numbers, where 0 is axiomatically distinct from the other numbers, and the other numbers in turn are distinct from other numbers in how they relate to 0.
One possible way to reason about this is that "O" is simply a label for an element of the space, much like "1" is a label for the successor of 0, whose label, "0", represents the first element. But in the case of natural numbers, we're attaching labels to elements which possess specific properties that can be expressed unequivocally in terms of the definitions and axioms of the natural numbers. We can't do this for an affine space.
Another way to look at it could be that we're not specifiying any particular point. The statement "point O is the origin the system" should then be understood as a tacit agreement between the participants of a hypothetical conversation: "pick whatever point you like and call it O". Since all relations in geometry are relations between at least two elements of the space, not "absolute" relations, and this space is homogeneous, whatever reasoning that follows "pick whatever point you like and call it O" would unwind in the same manner for any chosen point. This has the benefit of making applications to physics sound, by mapping the chosen point, which could be any point, to a particular point in reality, such as "point O is an abstract representation of the corner of this platform, to which the robot is attached, closest to the red door". But this still hasn't addressed the issue that  I can't, in a clear sense, pick a point, once again unlike "picking" the number 3, or 228, or 784248, since to pick a point, I should have someway of distinguishing it from others.
How is this issue addressed?

If you consider zero to be a distinguished natural number, then also the origin is a distinguished point of a vector space. In both cases it is the neutral element of addition. - If you exclude (e.g. by homogenity and isotropy) any differences between the points, then there is no distinguished point - by definition. - I do not see what the point of your question is.

@JoWehler I didn't ask about a vector space, I asked about structures such as affine spaces. I didn't use the word "origin" to mean "the zero element of a space with respect to some operation on that space", but as an arbitrary reference point someone chooses when operating with that space.

@JoWehler "If you exclude (e.g. by homogenity and isotropy) any differences between the points, then there is no distinguished point - by definition." - Yes, so how do I specify any particular point? That's the intention of my question.

You choose a system of coordinates to discriminate and identify points.

@JoWehler To choose a system of coordinates I must first discriminate a point to be the system's origin, so this reasoning becomes circular.

You may choose an arbitrary type of coordinate system and you may calibrate the coordinate system by any constellation of points. Hence I do not consider this method to be circular.

@JoWehler What do you mean by "constellation of points"? A set of points? If that's the case, how do you specify those points without resorting to the coordinate system you're trying to calibrate with those same points?

jvf I mark the points.

@JoWehler How do you mark abstract objects.....?

@ivf If you can distinguish two objects you can also mark them by this distinction.

@JoWehler But that's the point, we can't distinguish two points of an affine space in any sensible way, unless we know some additional structure. As you said: "If you exclude (e.g. by homogenity and isotropy) any differences between the points, then there is no distinguished point"

One has two distinguish between two different statements:

“A theory which is based on a given set considers each element of the set as equally good like any other.” Formally: On the set acts a group transitively as a symmetry group. I assume that's your case.
“One cannot distinguish each two points of the set.” In this case it makes neither sense to speak of different points at all, nor to speak of a set with distinct elements.


@JoWehler "2. 'One cannot distinguish each two points of the set.' In this case it makes neither sense to speak of different points at all, nor to speak of a set with distinct elements." But isn't this exactly what is done, for example, in Hilbert's axiomatization of geometry, or even Euclid's orginal postulates? There is no distinction between points, but we will liberally refer to different points with labels, without ever explicitly saying what point among all possible points is the one the label refers to. Which brings me back to my question: how could we do that?

@jvf see my answer: assuming that a point is given is always allowed, regardless of whether you can construct such a point at all. It is perfectly fine to prove a property for all elements of the empty set, for example, even though you can't construct a point of the empty set. This is the difference between input/output, premise/conclusion, assumption/claim, player/opponent, caller/callee, proof/refutation, and other similar dualities.

There are undefinable real numbers, by the way.

Relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44102/is-the-analysis-as-taught-in-universities-in-fact-the-analysis-of-definable-numb and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/423796/why-we-can-analytically-define-%ce%b5-in-dual-numbers-so-to-distinguish-%ce%b5-from

Can we prove it's inconsistent to choose such a point? I'm not clear on the formalism you are working under, but maybe this is any easy way forward for now: if there's no strong suspicion of mathematical inconsistency, why can't we just do so (choose), and then let the math flow from the being able to chose? Why cant I choose in the first place?

@JKusin in HoTT you can: see my answer. It's very intuitive: you can't pick a point from an abstract two-element set because there is nothing to tell the two points apart; if I presented you with the same set again but with the elements swapped, you would make a different choice, so this cannot be well-defined.

@NaïmFavier Is this an okay analogy since I don't know HoTT: we can't pick different elements of [0] = {0,-2,2,-4..} apart under addition mod 2? Like we actually can't do it mathematically. Even if we abuse the axiom of choice, like your answer's footnote?

No, it's a bit different. What you're saying is just that [0] = [-2] = [2] = ... in the quotient set ℤ/2ℤ. We can choose a representative of this equivalence class, say 0. My point is that we can't choose a representative of every two-element set in existence simultaneously, or uniformly.

The question only becomes meaningful once you specify which mathematical framework you are working in.  I will assume that your background framework is Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory (ZF).
In ZF, no choice is required to choose an element from a particular nonempty set (such as your affine space); here it doesn't matter that the points are "indistinguishable" from one another.
On the other hand, if you want to choose a point simultaneously for a family of nonempty sets, you will need the Axiom of Choice.  Indeed, being able to do this is equivalent to the Cartesian product of the family being nonempty.  The latter property is not provable in ZF (but only in ZFC).

Formally, there is no confusion between the assumptions of an argument and the actual result of the argument itself. In the language of type theory, you would write
X : AffineSpace, O : X ⊢ ℐ(O)
where ℐ is a judgement parametrised on an arbitrary point O of an arbitrary affine space X, to translate something like "let O be a point; then, ℐ(O)...". By contrast, the judgement
X : AffineSpace ⊢ O : X
or equivalently
⊢ f : (X : AffineSpace) → X
means that you can construct an explicit point of any arbitrary affine space. In univalent foundations, it should be possible to prove that this type is empty by transporting f(ℝ) along the identification ℝ = ℝ (as affine spaces) induced by a translation (+1) to get f(ℝ) = f(ℝ) + 1, a contradiction: this means that you cannot construct such an f.¹
On the other hand, you can prove that every affine space is merely inhabited (in the sense of the HoTT book), that is
X : AffineSpace ⊢ O : ∥ X ∥
Intuitively, this means that there is at least one point in every affine space X, but any choice is as good as any other.
Finally, if you fix an affine space X (say X = ℝ) then it might be possible to exhibit a point of that particular X (say 0):
⊢ ℝ : AffineSpace
⊢ 0 : ℝ
or equivalently
⊢ (ℝ, 0) : (X : AffineSpace) × X
Note that now both the space and the point are results/outputs instead of being assumptions/inputs.

¹ In ZFC set theory, you can probably abuse the axiom of choice to choose a point in every affine space, but this is not very satisfying.

From you comment: "we can't choose a representative of every two-element set in existence simultaneously, or uniformly". What about the AoC footnote though? It sounds like we can based on your footnote, and I thought as long as it's not inconsistent, it is satisfying mathematically.

This is where foundations start to matter. This form of choice is consistent with ZF set theory, but not HoTT/univalent foundations. Also, it is definitely non-constructive. These of these are fairly strong arguments against it IMO.

Yes I agree on your insistence on foundations/formalization for this question

Category theory would be helpful to you in this investigation, which focuses on relationships between collections of objects which arise implicitly due to their internal structure, but which is able to ignore the internal structure and look at the structure of the external relationships, which can encode the same information.
For example, the elementary theory of the category of sets axiomatizes set theory without explicitly describing "sets" as "collections with other sets inside of them". It just describes the relationships from one set to another, and it does so abstractly, so it could be generalized to anything with that pattern of relationship, even if it is not "a collection of elements".
https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCS
Similarly, category theory can be used to describe the structural relationships topological structures on sets have, to sets, other sets, and other topological structures on sets, without referring to "points" in a "space".
https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/point-free+topology
